# Does devise require session affinity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, cookies, devise, session-affinity

As I am using load balancer in my app, it becomes important to know whether devise uses cookie based authentication or only session based authentication?

It would be great to use cookie based authentication, then I do not have to reserve the same server for a signed it user for all his requests, and it will be easier to manage load balancing.

So, does devise use cookie based authentication out of the box? or do I have to enable it? or it supports session based authentication only?

Comment: Afaik it will always use the session store (but most session stores don't care about which backend server is used)

Comment: how would I make sure that it's backend server independent?

Comment: I think only file_store relies on affinity.

Comment: Can you please point me to a useful document on the topic?

Comment: There's http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session